# Task Queue Issue - Endpoint v2, Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, queue, task-queue, app.yaml, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

We are facing issues with taskqueues after recently updating the Endpoints API to version 2 in Google App Engine - Python. Following are the issues faced with respect to taskqueus,

1. Taskqueue **doesn't get added to the queue** at all , Just gets ignored and never executed.
2. Taskqueue get terminated with error - **"Process terminated because the backend was stopped."**

The most critical error is the first one where the task is just ignored and not added to the queue itself.

Details on the codebase and logs are attached along.

It would be great if someone can help us out here.

app.yaml (Server Settings)

```
   #version: 1
   runtime: python27
   api_version: 1
   threadsafe: true
   instance_class: F4
   automatic_scaling:
     min_idle_instances: 1
     max_idle_instances: 4  # default value
     min_pending_latency: 500ms  # default value
     max_pending_latency: 900ms
     max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

queue.yaml

```
 - name: allocateStore
     rate: 500/s
     bucket_size: 500
     max_concurrent_requests: 1000
     retry_parameters:
     task_retry_limit: 0
```

Adding task to queue:

```
    taskqueue.add(queue_name='allocateStore', url='/tasksStore/allocateStore')
```

Thanks, 
Navin Lr

Comment: did you check if the add operation throwing exception? I'm not sure what's the connection between updating endpoints API with taskqueue since they're separate  API

Comment: NO It doesnt throw any exception.